# How to Handle link and number from plain text

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, plaintext

I download user data, where I have a number, email, website and plain text in the description. My first question is how to find these links and number in text, recognize and use them? fe. when user click on the number, application should open new app to make phone call.

Example description text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, +44 798-09-09 consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut www.google.com et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis address@gmail.com ullamco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `autoLink` attribute for `TextView`. It handles automatically all links and its clicks.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    android:autoLink="phone" />
```

You can also use `autoLink="web"` or `autoLink="all"`.

You can see all possible values for `autoLink` from its [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoLink).